# Trello drag and drop effect

Tags: drag-and-drop, trello

Does anyone know how Trello does those pretty drag and drop effects, where the selected card angles slightly with the text visible?

I like to think I look at any site on the web and know roughly how everything is being done, but I've never seen an effect like that done seamlessly. Is it a pre-rendered image which is dynamically styled on the server and loaded when dragging starts?

Utterly trivial question I know!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Trello just uses a [CSS rotate transformation](http://davidwalsh.name/css-transform-rotate) on the `ui-sortable-helper`

```
.list-card.ui-sortable-helper {
   transform: rotate(3deg);
   -moz-transform: rotate(3deg);
   -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I've only just started to look at CSS3, had no idea it could rotate.